# Does the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{2}{n^2+2n}}$ depend at which $n$ the series starts?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to find the sum of the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{2}{n^2+2n}}$$

Now, this should be a telescopic series. It is equal to

$$2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2+2n}=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n(n+2)}}=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}{\left[{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2}}\right]}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)}$$

This series is in the same form of

$$\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\left(a_n-a_{n+k}\right)$$

In fact, $a_n=\frac 1 n$ and $a_{n+2}=\frac{1}{n+2}$. Since $k=2$ the series has this sum:

$$a_1+a_2=1+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$$

Now, my question is if it's safe to say that in a telescopic series it does not matter at which $n$ the series "starts". To find the sum we haven't considered $n=1$. It could have been any number. Any hints?

Comment: "...it does not matter..." - why?

Comment: Why shouldn't it?

Comment: To find the sum we haven't considered $n=1$. It could have been any number.

Comment: Could you write down explicitly the sum of a telescoping series? (And see that the answer depends on the first term of it... or maybe on the first few ones.)

Comment: "to argue using induction, don't forget the base".

Comment: "*To find the sum we haven't considered $n=1$*"  I'm not quite sure what you mean by that... The sum of your series is $\sum\limits_{n=\color{red}{1}}\frac{2}{n^2+2n} = a_{\color{red}{1}}+a_{\color{red}{1}+1}$ but if we had a different lowerbound, say $n=5$ we would have the sum being $\sum\limits_{n=\color{red}{5}}\frac{2}{n^2+2n} = a_{\color{red}{5}}+a_{\color{red}{5}+1}$ etc...  If you are talking about merely whether or not the series converges rather than what it converges *to*, then yes of course the lower limit doesn't matter.

Comment: @JMoravitz excellent thanks

Comment: @JMoravitz feel free to post that as an answer

Comment: @Cesare Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{2}{n^2+2n}}=S\le 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=\frac{\pi^2}3$$

we have that

$$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}{\frac{2}{n^2+2n}}=S-\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}{\frac{2}{n^2+2n}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider a telescopic series, (This one is easier to understand.)

$$\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{1+n}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{m}$$

Wouldn't it depend on what $'m'$ is?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter in the sense that:

1. If the sum converges, then it converges for any starting index
2. You can always transform the expression as a sum or difference of the sum starting from zero, plus or minus the missing terms.

Here, you can just see that some terms telescope when you compute the partial sum. Taking the limit, the term of high order cancels out and you get the right result.